# Solr documents get merged

Tags: solr, solrj

Solr 6.6.6

I run Solr/Zookeper in docker containers. After I create cores, I add a document with default values, that should never change.
It's my test environment, I start/stop container often.

Looks like sometimes (every few weeks) other document(s) from the same core get merged with the default one. `uniqueKey` is the same, but values of some other fields changes, and new dynamic fields are added.

I don't think it's some wrong update query, because `_updated_at` value of the document is not changed.

Is there some query that merges documents without touching `_updated_at`?
Any know bug that could cause it?

Comment: `_updated_at` is a field name provided by your own code or an update processor (which can be skipped) (Solr uses the `_version_` field internally). If you have multiple documents with the same uniquekey, the latter one will overwrite the previous one - so I'm guessing there is a duplicate uniquekey somewhere in your indexing code.

Comment: @MatsLindh yes, _updated_at comes from update processor, solr.TimestampUpdateProcessorFactory. Initially, there was no duplicated uniquekey. It is possible that my code creates another document with the same uniquekey, but then _updated_at should change...

Comment: That depends on whether that specific update chain runs for that document - maybe it has been submitted without an update chain specified (or with an overridden chain). Depending on your configuration that could be a possible issue at least.